# Ajax onClick of button with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure what I am doing wrong here...but I am trying to make a simple AJAX call to another page to insert a record.

This is my jQuery

```
        $('#send_group_chat').click(function() {
            var order_id = <?php echo $_GET['order']; ?>;
            var send_to_users = $('#selectuser_ids').val();
            var message = $('#chat_message');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'notes.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {action: 'insert_data', order_id: order_id, send_to_users: send_to_users, message:message},
                success: function( data ) {
                    $('#group_chat_history').html(data);
                }
            });
            //console.debug(send_to_users);
        });
```

Comment: And what console returns?

Comment: It should be `$('#chat_message').val()` you forgot `val()`

Comment: Oops. @Barmar thank you